# Unable to find Guardian Open Platform API Module on PYPI

Tags: python

I am currenly running Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I am looking for the Guardian OpenPlatform API module, but it is not listed on PYPI. I have had a look on Google, but I cant find anything that looks like a download link.

Does anyone know where I can get hold of this module?

Thanks

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/openplatform-python/, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guardian-openplatform/

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hello again. i was just looking at this but wasnt sure what link was for the download on the page (sorry if that sounds stupid)...

Comment: do you have pip installed?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes

Comment: @PadraicCunningham just tried downloading via pip with the following command 'pip install guardian-openplatform' and got an error that no downloads could be found?

Comment: the pypi version is an alpha release, I don't think it is even accessible on pypi. The google code has no setup.py so you would have to manually add the package to your python path.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham is there anywhere sites in particular that have tutorials on that? im looking at some stuff online, but im not sure where to start...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham manually installing a python package

Comment: you add it to your pythonpath, google pythonpath, I don't think the lib is very recent so may not be much use anyway

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ok, i will have a look and see if i can manage to install it manually, but failing that i will go back to seeing if i can build some code manually.

Comment: there is no setup.py in the code so you can only add it to your path somehow.